# GitHub not copying all files

Tags: github, github-for-mac

I am using GitHub desktop for MAC, but I notice to create a new repository, when I choose the folder of my XCODE project the file ".xcodeproj" is grayed, and do not copy to github web site this file.

Any help?

Cheers

Comment: What are the contents of your .gitignore file?

Answer (score 1):

Check inside the top directory of the repo for a file ".gitignore" and see if a line in that file could be matching your missing file(s).  If so, just remove the line, if you want the file.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention no gitignore :(